# Get variables from Entry PYTHON 3

Tags: python, function, user-interface, variables, tkinter

so I'm coding this GUI-program (using tkinter) and I'm using three Entryboxes in the same function. I wanna use their values in the main function, so how do I get the values into some kind of global variable or in a way that I can use them in a different function?

```
def options():

    options_root = Tk()

    textFrame = Frame(options_root)
    textFrame.grid()

    widthlabel = Label(textFrame, text="w:", justify=LEFT)
    widthlabel.grid(column="0", row="0")
    widthinput = Entry(textFrame)
    widthinput.grid(column="1", row="0")

    heightlabel = Label(textFrame, text="h:", justify=LEFT)
    heightlabel.grid(column="0", row="1")
    heightinput = Entry(textFrame)
    heightinput.grid(column="1", row="1")

    mlabel = Label(textFrame, text="m:", justify=LEFT)
    mlabel.grid(column="0", row="2")
    minput = Entry(textFrame)
    minput.grid(column="1", row="2")

    width = widthinput.get()
    height = heightinput.get()
    m = minput.get()


    start_game_button = Button(options_root, text="Start", justify=LEFT, command=lambda:tabort(options_root))
    start_game_button.grid(column="0",row="3")
    exit_button = Button(options_root, text = "Exit", justify=LEFT, command=exit)
    exit_button.grid(column="1", row="3")

    mainloop()

def main():

    options()

    w = widthinput.get()
    h = heightinput.get()
    m = minput.get()

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep a reference to the widgets, then use the `get()` method. This becomes much easier if you design your application as a class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.width_entry = tk.Entry(...)
        self.height_entry = tk.Entry(...)
        self.minput_entry = tk.Entry(...)
        ...
    def main(...):
        w = self.width_entry.get()
        h = self.height_entry.get()
        m = self.input_entry.get()
        ...

...
app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So now I got this error, doing it with a class.
w = ins.width()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @tivon: what part of tht etror message don't you understand? It's telling you exactly what the error is. You seem to think `width` is a function but python thinks it's an int.